# Non-Modal Popup without fading out the BackGround screen

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, popup, non-modal

I'd like to create a popup dialog box in silverlight with a Input-box and a Ok and Cancel button. And the speciality of popup should be that It should not fade-out the master-background screen. And the backGround screen should be scrollable and visibile clearly.
Currently i am using just a Javascript Prompt box on my screen, but its look and feel is not so pleasing.. i am looking for something having a smoother look.

Answer (score 1):

Using Silverlights [ChildWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow%28VS.95%29.aspx) you'll get a folowing look . Fading out can be disabled though.
[image: ChildWindow]

**UPDATE:**
[Non modal refactoring](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/05/10/silverlight-childwindow-non-modal-refactor.aspx)

[image: Non modal child dialog]

Comment: The main thing i needed was that the childwindow should NOT fade out my Background screen. And the Background screen should be scrollable and editable even though the child window is open. I am unable to achieve the it with the childwindow.. i have used the following OverlayOpacity="0" Background="Transparent" Opacity="1" OverlayBrush="Transparent" but of no use..

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight there is a [ChildWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)-Control that you can use as PopUp. The ChildWindow has properties to specify the [Opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow.overlayopacity%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and the [Background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow.overlaybrush%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of the Overlay, so that you can define if the Background screen is visible.

Comment: The main thing i needed was that the childwindow should NOT fade out my Background screen. And the Background screen should be scrollable and editable even though the child window is open. I am unable to achieve the it with the childwindow.. i have used the following OverlayOpacity="0" Background="Transparent" Opacity="1" OverlayBrush="Transparent" but of no use..

Comment: To be precise i want the child window to be NON-MODAL !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ChildWindow control to do this.
And even you can handle the events of this popup window on the parent window.